# Calling doskey /reinstall from a script

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a BAT script that takes a password as an argument. I'd like to remove all mentions of the password from the command history and the output window. I added this to the end of my script:

```
cls
doskey /reinstall
```

The first time I ran my script, it worked exactly as intended. When I ran it a second time, though, it looks like `doskey` didn't do anything. I press the <kbd>▲</kbd> key and still get the command coming up.

Why does this only work once? How can I get this to work for multiple runs of the script? When it's being used for real, I expect it to be run back to back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following instead:

```
cls
doskey /listsize=0
doskey /listsize=200
```

This works across multiple calls, and doesn't interfere with the history after the script is called.

Comment: However, it will stop working once `doskey /reinstall` is run, or `doskey /reinstall /exename=cmd.exe` (the default executable name).

Comment: @eryksun That's fine, as I don't anticipate the `doskey` command being used outside the script, and it's not used elsewhere within the script.

Comment: I looked at this problem in the debugger. Reinstalling is based on an undocumented console function `ExpungeConsoleCommandHistory`, which is implemented in the console (i.e. conhost.exe) via `FindExeCommandHistory` and `EmptyCommandHistory`. The latter clears a flag in the history buffer that indicates the buffer is allocated and ready. Once it's cleared, `FindExeCommandHistory` will *never* find this history buffer again. But it's the single history buffer for the current console client process (i.e. cmd.exe), so even `SetConsoleNumberOfCommands` (i.e. `/listsize`) won't work anymore.

Comment: It's a bug that when it reuses the history buffer it doesn't set the allocated and ready flag again, which in turn breaks every function that relies on `FindExeCommandHistory`.

Comment: @eryksun That makes sense, and lines up with what I saw. I tried using `/listsize` only after `/reinstall` was flaking out, and that didn't work anymore either, further confusing me